# MKMapView Road Map

Tags: iphone

How to Get Route from user current Location to Destination location in MkMapView?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle that yourself. Get the gps data somewhere for the route and draw the lines yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's something allowed in Mapkit. I believe it's part of the restrictions to prevent Mapkit from being used for a turn by turn application.

Comment: I heard this too, thats why all the gps apps do n ot use map view they have their own maps

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapKit for showing maps, but when it comes to routing you'll have to launch out to the Maps app. In the URL launching Maps you can pass the destination's lat/long coordinates and have it place pin. The user can then find their way there from their current location.